# How to successfully embed a youtube video on facebook application tab

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fbml

I have created simple facebook app. I have a profile tab(for facebook pages) where I have embed a youtube video.

```
<fb:swf swfbgcolor="000000" imgstyle="border-width:3px; border-color:white;" swfsrc='http://www.youtube.com/v/xxxxxxxxxx'  imgsrc='http://img.youtube.com/vi/xxxxxxxxxx/2.jpg' width='340' height='270' />
```

The image appears fine. But onclick It does not play the video.

I appreciate any help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in order to achieve that you have to correctly replace the `swfsrc` attribute value with the one of the youtube video you want.

open the youtube video link, click on the `embed` button and look at the first `<param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/cNgf6fd88g8?fs=1&amp;hl=en_US"></param>` tag. copy that value (without the query string) and paste it on your swfsrc attribute value. that's all. enjoy ;)

Comment: impossible, i tested it before posting. please post the entire fb:swf you're having so i can tell exactly what is the error ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
<iframe 
    id="yt" 
    src="//www.youtube.com/embed/i8h9_2Ph5VY/?wmode=opaque&amp;version=3&amp;theme=dark&amp;width=810&amp;height=456&amp;autoplay=0&amp;rel=0&amp;showinfo=0&amp;iv_load_policy=3&amp;&amp;vq=hd720&amp;hd=1&amp;html5=1&amp;enablejsapi=1&amp;playerapiid=main" 
    frameborder="0" 
    scrolling="no" 
    allowfullscreen="true" 
    webkitallowfullscreen="true" 
    mozallowfullscreen="true" 
    style="width: 810px; height: 456px;">
</iframe>
```